# Apt sources.list problem , packages not found?

Tags: apt, software-sources, wicd

I am trying to install WICD but getting following errors on my ubuntu 10.04 box

```
sudo apt-get install wicd


Err http://archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu/ lucid/universe python-wicd 1.7.0+ds1-2
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk:80 (103.29.60.18). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err http://archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu/ lucid/main python-iniparse 0.3.1-1
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk:http:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu/ lucid/universe wicd-daemon 1.7.0+ds1-2
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk:http:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu/ lucid/universe wicd-gtk 1.7.0+ds1-2
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk:http:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu/ lucid/universe wicd 1.7.0+ds1-2
  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk:http:
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/python-wicd_1.7.0+ds1-2_all.deb  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk:80 (103.29.60.18). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-iniparse/python-iniparse_0.3.1-1_all.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk:http:
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-daemon_1.7.0+ds1-2_all.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk:http:
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd-gtk_1.7.0+ds1-2_all.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk:http:
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wicd/wicd_1.7.0+ds1-2_all.deb  Unable to connect to archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk:http:
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your software sources and specifically where you are trying to get them from, the first error gives you the clue.

`Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.schoolnet.lk:80 (103.29.60.18). - connect (111: Connection refused)`

Open Ubuntu Software Center -> Edit -> Software Sources.

Try changing your software sources to another server and updating.

---

The following screenshots will show you how this is done;

Click the dropdown arrow in the 'Download from' box

[image: Software Sources 1]

You can either select 'Main Server' (recommended) or 'Other'

[image: Software Sources 2]

If you select 'Other' it will then open another dialogue box which will give you more options and you can choose the best one for your location manually.

Select the server you wish to use then hit 'Choose server' then close out. 
You can then type `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal and download the program.

[image: Software Sources 3]

Comment: change my software sources to what or from where ??

Comment: Updated answer to show how this is done.

Comment: Can You tell me that How can I do this in terminal so that I can be more cooler !!! :D ??